# Script root path issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

In my JSP I can get the context path like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:message code="resources.location"/>/js/registration.js"></script>
```

But in my `registration.js` need an ajax call I need the root path how to get that.

Any suggestion?

my js code

```
var lottoRequestHandler = new LottoRequestHandler();

function ContactService(){
    this.postContactUserData = function(data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        lottoRequestHandler.makeAjaxRequest(data, '/app/contact/registration', 'POST', successCallback, errorCallback);

    }

}
```

ajax code
rootContext this is hard coaded I want to it will came from jsp

```
 this.makeAjaxRequest = function (parm, requestUrl, method, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            var rootContext = 'http://localhost:8080/lotto';
            var requestType = 'jsonp';
            if(method === 'POST') {
                requestType = 'json';
            }
            $.ajax({
                complete: function() {

                },
                type: method,
                url: rootContext + requestUrl,
                crossDomain: true,
                data: parm,
                dataType: requestType,
                //contentType: 'application/javascript',
                async: true,
                success: function(response) {
                    if(typeof successCallback === 'function') {
                        successCallback(response);
                    }
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    if(typeof errorCallback === 'function') {
                        errorCallback();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

my jsp calling these file

```
<script src='<spring:message code="resources.location"/>/js/requestHandlers/lottoRequestHandler.js'></script>
        <script src="<spring:message code="resources.location" />/js/services/contactService.js"></script>
```

It work fine but the context is hard coaded can't be use in production.

Comment: have you tried `/` in the js file. should give you the domain root and you can build up from there

Comment: How Can you give an example.

Comment: please show the js code that requires the root path

Comment: @atmd please se mu coad.

Comment: how about `var rootContext = '/lotto';`

Comment: it will work fin but ant case changing the port or context root name.this have to change

Comment: is you root content the domain? why would that change?

Answer (score 0):

Define a  tag in the head section of the html and if you are using apache use RewriteBase

Comment: a base* tag (it got filtered)

Comment: apache for what server

Comment: sorry I don't know about RewriteBase. any reference example.